# Analytics.js loaded twice into DOM w/ GTM/GA/Optimize set-up

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

We're using Google Tag Manager to load GA into the site (on gtm.load). We load Google Optimize tag on top of that, using Google's recommendations (https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6314801?hl=en). This requires the loading of GA to be a trigger for the Google Optimize tag. We also use the anti-flicker snippet (https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7100284?hl=en).
With this setup, when the page is done loading, there are two instances of analytics.js showing up in the DOM. Now different web optimization sites are telling me the script is loaded and parsed twice, which is of course unwanted behaviour.. But I'm not sure if that's actually the case, because I'm not seeing anything that points to that when looking at the chaining, for instance.

Is this normal behaviour?

[screen of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQsTZ.jpg)

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue.  Were you able to get any resolution after all this time (7 months)?  Or have you accepted this as standard behavior and moved on? :-)

Comment: Zero resolution. Which seems odd; our setup isn't that complicated or specific, you'd expect the issue (and subsequent solution) to pop up more often. Good luck figuring out out.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll get with our Google rep and see what they have to say.

Comment: @dhildreth Cool, I've posted it on the different Google Product fora and got nothing. Also contacted the A/B testing company that suggested the implementation, and they acknowledged the issue, but also had no answer. It'd be great if you're more successful though.

Comment: Getting the same issue, can anyone help on this?